# Importing a set of images from a resource folder in java

Tags: java, image, file, animation, directory

I want to import a set of 60 images from a directory folder in my project to bufferedImage[]. I can import a single image but when I try to write a method to import multiple I get a nullPointerException.
specifically from trying to get the length of the directory *Number of Images* in the directory. I believe it has to do with my file path, but have not been able to find relevant resource to solve my problem.

** code I am working on **

```
    private void importImgs() {
        int numImgs = new File("/res/moon/").listFiles().length;
        moonIdle =  new BufferedImage[numImgs];

        
        for(int i = 0; i < numImgs; i++) {
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/moon/" + i + 1 + ".png");
            
            try {
                moonIdle[i] = ImageIO.read(is);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

** code to import single image working **

```
    private void importImg() {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/moon/1.png");
        
        try {
            moon = ImageIO.read(is);
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
                
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I was trying to get the number of images in a directory from my project. I was using
    `int numImgs = new File("/res/moon/").listFiles().length;`

I was hoping to get 60 bc I have 60 images for a animation of a rotating moon. but I get a NullPointerException:
Cannot read the array length because the return value of
"java.io.File.listFiles()" is null

Comment: So, assuming for a second that the images are embedded resources (ie included in your Jar), then `int numImgs = new File("/res/moon/").listFiles().length;` isn't going to work, as `/res/moon` is not longer a directory, it's actually a zip entry.  There is a really (imho) janky way to this, but it's some what error prone the resources exist in different jars/libraries, so, instead, what I prefer to do, is generate a text file which can be included.

Comment: This would list all the resources.  At runtime, you'd read this file (using `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`) and then you'd iterate over this list, loading the resource.  You could generate the "list file" either manually or as part of your build process

Comment: If you know, ahead of time, the number of images, just make that number of iterations

Comment: I misread the question, so I deleted my answer. However, there is still a problem trying to do integer addition and string concatenation at once. You need to add parenthesis like `"/res/moon/" + (i + 1) + ".png"` (or just loop from 1 instead of 0 and don't add 1), otherwise you'll get `/res/moon/01.png` and another NPE...

Comment: I am fairly new to Java and stack, so bare with me. I was hoping to be able to use it on directories that I may add in to get the number of files. The answer solve my issue, and showed me the proper way to import images.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `/res/moon/` is a File object means something very different from specifying the same string as a resource path.

`new File("/res/moon")` refers to a “res” directory *in the root of your drive,* not in your project.  On Windows, this probably refers to `C:\res\moon`.  On other systems, it’s `/res/room` at the root of the file system, alongside /bin, /lib, and /usr.  I doubt this is what you intended.

This is where your NullPointerException is coming from:  `listFiles()` fails because you don’t have that directory in the root if your drive.  listFiles returns null when it fails, instead of properly throwing an exception.  (This is a known weakness of the File class.  The File class should not be used anymore, except with APIs that require it;  the replacement for it is the [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) class and the [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) class.)

For reading internal application resources, one must not use File (or Path).  Not only is it unreliable because it has to make assumptions about your application’s [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), it also won’t work at all if you ever package your application in a .jar file.

A .jar file is **one file.**  Resources inside it are not files;  you cannot read them as files.  You cannot list them as files.  They are just parts of a compressed archive.

So, how should you get the total number of images?  Easy—you already know.  You said yourself that you have 60 images, so just put something in your class like this:

```
private static final int IMAGE_COUNT = 60;
```

You have another problem here:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/moon/" + i + 1 + ".png");
```

If you add this line right before it:

```
System.out.println("/res/moon/" + i + 1 + ".png");
```

You will see that it’s not doing what you intended.  The `+` operator works left-to-right, so no mathematical addition is taking place.  You can easily fix it with parentheses:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/moon/" + (i + 1) + ".png");
//              math is performed before string concatenation  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

If you look at the documentation for [the methods of ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#method-summary), you will see there is a read(URL) method.  This is much easier to use when loading resources:

```
for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++) {
    URL imageLocation = getClass().getResource("/res/moon/" + (i + 1) + ".png");
    moonIdle[i] = ImageIO.read(imageLocation);
}
```

No need to worry about closing an InputStream.  (Notice the use of getResource instead of getResourceAsStream.)

Instead of ignoring an IOException for each image, place the entire loop inside one try/catch.  If you can’t load an image, you certainly don’t want to keep going as if nothing’s wrong.

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++) {
        URL imageLocation = getClass().getResource("/res/moon/" + (i + 1) + ".png");
        moonIdle[i] = ImageIO.read(imageLocation);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Finally, I assume your application will not work properly without those images loaded, since there won’t be much for a user to see.  Instead of ignoring an IOException, treat it as a fatal error.

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++) {
        String resourcePath = "/res/moon/" + (i + 1) + ".png";

        URL imageLocation = getClass().getResource(resourcePath);

        if (imageLocation == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Missing image in application: "
                + "\"" + resourcePath + "\"");
        }

        moonIdle[i] = ImageIO.read(imageLocation);

        if (moonIdle[i] == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Invalid image in application at " + imageLocation);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load internal image!", e);
}
```

Notice that the above code does not just call printStackTrace in its catch block and keep going as if nothing’s wrong.  That’s because something *is* wrong—seriously wrong, in fact.  The application cannot run properly without those images!  The correct course of action is to halt the program logic, which is what exceptions are designed to do.  Rarely is it a good idea to just print/log an exception and keep going as if nothing is wrong.

Also, notice that the caught exception is itself passed as an argument when constructing the RuntimeException.  This guarantees that the original exception, and its stack trace information, are not lost.  Eventually, some code at some level will print that stack trace, even if it’s Java SE itself who does so.